# How to draw a separator across a panel (GridBagLayout)

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, gridbaglayout, jseparator

I am trying to add a `JSeparator` across a `Panel` in `GridBagLayout`, but it's not showing up.

I tried options like

```
panel.add(new JSeparator());
```

and

```
panel.add(new JSeparator(SwingConstants.HORIZONTAL));
```

None of them are giving a visible separator.

Answer (score 3):

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Separators](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/separator.html) where you will find the statement:

> Separators have almost no API and are extremely easy to use as long as you keep one thing in mind: In most implementations, a vertical separator has a preferred height of 0, and a horizontal separator has a preferred width of 0. This means a separator is not visible unless you either set its preferred size or put it in under the control of a layout manager such as BorderLayout or BoxLayout that stretches it to fill its available display area.

So if you use it with a `GridBagLayout`, then you will need to specify proper constraints so that the separator fills all the columns for the given row. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) for more information on the constraints and working examples. The tutorial demonstrates how to have a button fill 3 columns, so try replacing the button with your separator.